# Google Cloud Storage - How to limit access to specific bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I'd like to give an application access to *one* of my Google Storage buckets by giving it a suitable OAuth2 token.

If I understand https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication correctly, then there is no way to limit a token to a specific bucket.

What is the easiest / recommended way to create a token with limited access? I guess I could create an entirely new Google account just for this purpose, adjust the ACLs of the bucket to give access to the new user as well, and then create an OAuth token using that user. But that seems... awkward and not very scalable.

(In case it matters: the application is using the [OAuth2 device flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices), i.e. it gives me a Google URL that I have to visit and use to log in)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service account, with access limited to the required bucket. 
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts

Comment: This seems like a promising account. However, having created the service account, how can I use it to create the OAuth token? The application uses the [device flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices), so it gives me a Google URL where I have to log in - but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a service account...

Comment: Ι don't think GCP IAM service accounts provide for limiting access to specific (nameD) resources, as for example in the case of AWS permissions

Answer (score 1):

Use Bucket ACLs and grant the user's email address to the bucket. The user's email address must be part of Google Accounts or G Suite that the user logs in with (to Google Accounts).

The following `gsutil` example will grant `john.doe@example.com` the permission `write` on Bucket `example-bucket`:

```
gsutil acl ch -u john.doe@example.com:WRITE gs://example-bucket
```

Documentation:

[GSUTIL - ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl)

Comment: There is no other user, only me wanting to run application without giving it full access to all by buckets. My question is if there is a more elegant way than creating a new dummy user for this.

Comment: Are you saying - I want to restrict my credentials but only when running from device X?

Comment: Pretty much, though I wouldn't say "from device X" but "certain code" - be that to protect against bugs or because I don't fully trust it. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough in the question.